# Proof of indexed family set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I am stuck at the following exercise in Velleman's How To Prove it:

> Suppose $\{A_i\mid i \in I\}$ is a family of sets. Prove that if $\mathscr P\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\right) \subseteq \bigcup_{i\in I}\mathscr P(A_i) $, then there is some $i\in I$ such that $\forall j\in I(A_j\subseteq A_i) $. ($\mathscr P$ means powerset.)

I tried expanding this into its logical form and proceed, but its logical form has too many variables and too complicated of a structure that I couldn't get my head around it, so I turned to the solution:

i) Suppose $\mathscr P\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\right) \subseteq \bigcup_{i\in I}\mathscr P(A_i) $.

ii). Clearly $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i \subseteq \bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$, so $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i \in \mathscr P\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\right)$, and therefore $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i \in \bigcup_{i\in I}\mathscr P(A_i)$.

I don't see how $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i \in \mathscr P\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\right)$ leads to $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i \in \bigcup_{i\in I}\mathscr P(A_i)$; in fact despite knowing its logical form $\exists i\in I\, \forall y(y\in x \to y\in A_i) $, I don't even know how to explain $\bigcup_{i\in I}\mathscr P(A_i)$ in ordinary language!

But even if I am to ignore this, there are further trouble ahead:

iii. By the definition of union of a family, this means that there is some $i \in I$ such that $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i \subseteq A_i$.

Does this mean $\exists i\in I \left(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i \subseteq A_i\right)$? But where is this coming from?! It seems that the subset comes from the definition of powerset, but I don't see how $\bigcup_{i\in I}\mathscr P(A_i)$ will yield this.

iv. Now let $j\in I$ be arbitrary. Then it is not hard to see that $A_j \subseteq \bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$, so $A_j \subseteq A_i$.

For me it is vacuously true that 'it's not hard', because I can't even understand what he was doing in the prior steps.

I am a self-teaching student so I am really grateful for any help on this, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s start with $\bigcup_{i\in I}\mathscr P(A_i)$. For each $i\in I$, $\mathscr{P}(A_i)$ is the family of all subsets of $A_i$. The union of all of these families is the collection of all sets that are subsets of at least one $A_i$. That is,

$$x\in\bigcup_{i\in I}\mathscr{P}(A_i)\quad\text{iff}\quad\exists i\in I\,(x\subseteq A_i)\;.$$

Since $x\subseteq A_i$ if and only if $x\in\mathscr{P}(A_i)$, this is just an application of the fact that if $\{X_i:i\in I\}$ is any indexed family of sets, then

$$x\in\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i\quad\text{iff}\quad\exists i\in I\,(x\in X_i)\;,$$

with $X_i=\mathscr{P}(A_i)$.

Now let’s look at $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i \in \bigcup_{i\in I}\mathscr P(A_i)$. We know that $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i \in \mathscr P\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\right)$, and we’re assuming that

$$\mathscr P\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\right) \subseteq \bigcup_{i\in I}\mathscr P(A_i)\;,$$

so in fact we have

$$\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i \in \mathscr P\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\right)\subseteq\bigcup_{i\in I}\mathscr P(A_i)$$

and hence

$$\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i \in\bigcup_{i\in I}\mathscr P(A_i)\;:$$

that’s just an application of the fact that if $x\in y\subseteq z$, then $x\in z$.

Now to avoid notational clutter temporarily let $a=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$; we’ve just seen that $a\in\bigcup_{i\in I}\mathscr{P}(A_i)$. As we saw up at the top, this means that there is some $i\in I$ such that $a\subseteq A_i$. At this point your source slips up a little, expanding $a$ to its original form and writing

$$\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\subseteq A_i\;.$$

This is incorrect: the $i$ on the lefthand side is an index variable, a dummy variable over which we take the union, while the $i$ on the right is a *specific* member of $i$ such that $a\in A_i$. We can fix this in a couple of ways. One is to make it more obvious that the $i$ on the right is a specific element of $I$ by changing it to $i_0$: the fact that $a\in\bigcup_{i\in I}\mathscr{P}(A_i)$ means that there is some particular $i_0\in I$ such that $a\subseteq A_{i_0}$, i.e., such that

$$\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\subseteq A_{i_0}\;.\tag{1}$$

The alternative would have been to change the index variable: it’s also true that $a=\bigcup_{j\in I}A_j$, so once we have a specific $i\in I$ such that $a\subseteq A_i$, we can write

$$\bigcup_{j\in I}A_j\subseteq A_i\;.$$

I’ll go with the first corrected version, with $(1)$.

Now the conclusion is pretty straightforward. For each $j\in I$ we have $A_j\subseteq\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ (by an easy application of the definition of the union); combining this with $(1)$, we get $A_j\subseteq A_{i_0}$. This $i_0\in I$ satisfies the conclusion of the theorem: $\forall j\in I\,(A_j\subseteq A_{i_0})$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation Professor! The details really helped me a lot to understand the proof. But I still don't quite get your last paragraph. For the $\forall j\in I A_j \subseteq\bigcup_{i\in I}\mathscr P(A_i)$, which part did you apply the def. of the union on to derive this?

Sorry about the late reply as I am working full time and didn't get to read it till yesterday

Comment: @Daniel: You’re welcome! To answer your question, let $j\in I$, and suppose that $x\in A_j$; in order to show that $A_j\subseteq\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$, we must show that $x\in\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$. By definition that will be true if there is an $i\in I$ such that $x\in A_i$, and there is: take $i=j$.

Comment: Thank you so much Professor! Just one final, curious question: you mentioned the theorem if$x\in y \subseteq z, then x\in z$. What if y is an empty set? Since it is automatically false that an empty set has an element, it would render the subset relation false, thus the entire if...then true (since the antecedent/if clause is false). Would that be an instance of vacuous truth?

Comment: @Daniel: The statement ‘if $x\in\varnothing\subseteq z$, then $x\in z$’ is indeed true for the reason that you give — the antecedent is false — but it’s a bit different from the statements that are usually described as vacuously true. An asymmetric relation, for instance, is vacuously antisymmetric, but this is because no elements of the underlying set satisfy the antecedent of the implication defining antisymmetry, not because that antecedent is internally contradictory. I’d rather classify this implication with ‘If $1=0$, then $2=0$’: true for formal reasons, simply because the ...

Comment: ... antecedent is necessarily false, and uninteresting otherwise.

Comment: Thank you so much Professor for your detailed explanations and patience! :)

Comment: @Daniel: You’re very welcome!